# Remove year, brackets and dot from @onlinesource in footnote

Tags: biblatex, online

This is my MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,]{biblatex}

\urlstyle{rm}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @online{blk,
      url = {http://www.blk-bonn.de/papers/forum-bildung/band06.pdf},
      date-added = {2014-02-09 12:34:08 +0000},
      date-modified = {2014-02-09 13:32:07 +0000},
          urldate = {2014-02-04}
    }

@article{test1,
    Author = {Shen Ain and Brian W. Kernighan},
    Date-Modified = {2014-02-04 20:18:03 +0000},
    Journal = {Operations Research},
    Title = {An Effective Heuristic Algorithm for the Travelling-Salesman Problem},
    Volume = {21},
    Year = {1973}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a cite for online \footcite{blk}

And here is a cite for article \footcite{test1}

\end{document}
```

this gives me:

[image]

Now, I remove the "URL:" in front of the URL:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
```

and change the text for the date url from "(Besucht am xx.xx.xxx)" to "aus dem Internet entnommen am" with:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{aus dem Internet entnommen am #1}
```

Now I have:

[image]

And Now, I want to remove the year, the brackets around the year and the dot *only* from '@online', but I have no idea how to achieve this...

Comment: Which dot do you mean? -- I am getting an other result. Do you use the newest version of `biblatex`?

Comment: the dot after the (2014). <--- in front of the URL

Comment: my bib latex version seems to be 2.8a... yes, that would be the result i would like to have ;)

Comment: i have biber 1.8....

Comment: i think it is kind of correct in 1.8, because of the authoryear-setting. When i add an author to the @online-Source, than it will be in front of the Year, like the article.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of your entry. Related to the documentation you can find: *`online`: Required fields: author/editor,title,year/date,url*

Comment: i found, that the preferred entry should be electronically now. Hmpf.. helped myself by downgrading to 1.7 of biber

Comment: Hmm, `@electronic` is a (legacy) alias for `@online`, and as such requires `author`/`editor`, `title`, `year`/`date`, `url`. Do you want only the `url` and `urldate` to be shown in every `\footcite` for `@online`? For that particular entry in your mwe though, there *are* author, title and date information available.

Comment: And how would you like `@online` to appear in the bibliography?